# Ionic assets doesn't work when deployed on angular

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I made an ionic app with

`@ionic/angular ^6.1.9`
`@capacitor/android 4.3.0`
`@angular/core ^14.0.0`

when served in browser everything works but when deployed on android, i've got no translations, no icons and a lot of errors for polyfill.js

Here are these errors

E/Capacitor/Plugin: MalformedURLException java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ./assets/i18n/fr.json

E/Capacitor/Plugin: MalformedURLException java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /svg/add.svg

E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/polyfills.js - Line 1 - Msg: Unhandled Promise rejection: MalformedURLException

Does somebody have an idea on what's the problem, i compared angular.json and TranslateLoader with another project but it's the same, i don't know why i works with a project and not with another

Here is my angular.json build assets options

```
    "assets": [
        {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "src/assets",
            "output": "assets"
        },
        {
            "glob": "**/*.svg",
            "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
            "output": "./svg"
        }
    ],
```

my package.json dependencies

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
        "@awesome-cordova-plugins/splash-screen": "^5.44.0",
        "@awesome-cordova-plugins/status-bar": "^5.44.0",
        "@capacitor-community/barcode-scanner": "^3.0.0",
        "@capacitor-community/electron": "^4.1.0",
        "@capacitor-community/sqlite": "^4.1.0",
        "@capacitor/android": "4.3.0",
        "@capacitor/app": "^4.0.0",
        "@capacitor/camera": "^4.1.2",
        "@capacitor/core": "^4.0.0",
        "@capacitor/dialog": "^4.0.0",
        "@capacitor/filesystem": "^4.0.0",
        "@capacitor/haptics": "^4.0.0",
        "@capacitor/ios": "4.3.0",
        "@capacitor/keyboard": "^4.0.0",
        "@capacitor/network": "^4.0.1",
        "@capacitor/preferences": "^4.0.1",
        "@capacitor/status-bar": "^4.0.0",
        "@capacitor/toast": "^4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
        "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
        "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^3.0.0",
        "jeep-sqlite": "^1.6.2",
        "json-concat": "^0.0.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.37",
        "replace": "^1.2.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.2.0",
        "typeorm": "^0.3.10",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
        "@angular/cli": "^14.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.0",
        "@capacitor/cli": "^4.0.0",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
        "@ionic/lab": "3.2.13",
        "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
        "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
        "eslint": "^7.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
        "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.14",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
        "typescript": "~4.7.3"
    },
```

My translateLoader

```
    
    export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
        let suffix = `.json`;

        if (environment.buildVersion) {
            suffix += '?v=' + environment.buildVersion;
        }

        return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', suffix);
    }

    @NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            defaultLanguage: environment.defaultLocale,
            loader: {provide: TranslateLoader, useFactory: createTranslateLoader, deps: [HttpClient]}
        }),
    ],
    ...
```

Thank you for your help